# Pass Data to Form to Store in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I am collecting addresses in a Google Spreadsheet using a web form. But I am collecting those addresses for multiple purposes. I would like to store an "identifier" in the spreadsheet which I can pass in from the form URL.

Is there some variable I can pass into the form's URL that I can then store in the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you.

http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=160000

You can send the value as entry_0 to the first field, entry_1 to t etc.,